# Take and remove elements from a Ruby Set in one operation

Tags: ruby, set

I have a Set of elements from which I want to take and remove the first few elements a bunch of times.  Is there a shorter way (so one operation instead of two) to do that than this:

```
require 'set'
s = Set[1, 2, 3, 4]       # => #<Set: {1, 2, 3, 4}> 

first_two = s.take(2)     # => [1, 2]
s.subtract(first_two)     # => #<Set: {3, 4}>
```

(So basically I'm wondering whether I'm overlooking a `shift` for Sets)

Comment: You could easily wrap that in a helper (if you're interested in usability). Or are you also interested in atomicity?

Comment: I was mainly interested in usability, but your comment about atomicity may be very relevant for anyone stumbling in this question. If you need that, I think the nest option is to decorate the Set with a class of your own. Either that, or reimplement Set in C.

Comment: Or simply monkeypatch `Set` and use `Hash#delete` which is atomic.

Comment: As long as the `take` and the `delete` are two seperate Ruby operations, another thread can be scheduled to run in between them, whether or not they are in a monkeypatched Set method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no shorter way using builtin methods.

There is an [open feature request](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4553) for a method to return and remove one element; you may want to help refine the API?

Answer (score 5):

You could add a new method `take!` (or `remove!` or whatever name seems appropriate) to the Set class:

```
class Set
  def take!(args)
    taken = self.take(args)
    self.subtract(taken)
    return taken
  end
end

a = Set[1, 2, 3, 4] # <Set: {1, 2, 3, 4}>
a.take!(2) # <Set: {1, 2}>
a # <Set: {3, 4}>
```

Comment: I believe the question is if there is some existing method to do this. BTW, both `self.` are redundant in your code, so is the `return`.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html:

> Set implements a collection of **unordered** values with no duplicates.
>   This is a hybrid of Array's intuitive inter-operation facilities and
>   Hash's fast lookup.

It would be odd and probably illogical to implement methods like shift and pop on an object that knows nothing about *index*.

Comment: I think the doc means that the elements are not sorted, in contrast with `SortedSet`. Order in a set is guaranteed (in 1.9+), as it relies on Hash.

Comment: I said 'the first few' in the question, but actually I don't care which elements they are. I just want to remove `n` elements from the Set and do something with them.

Comment: `take` does return in a specific order, I believe the same order might be used by `pop`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but here's my solution. Convert the set to an array first, and then all Enumerable methods are available. Take 2 from the array and then be sure to also remove the from the set. The two values from the set get removed and returned.

```
require 'set'
s = Set[1, 2, 3, 4]     # => #<Set: {1, 2, 3, 4}> 

first_two = s.to_a.take(2).tap {|a| s.subtract(a)}  # => [1, 2]
s                       # => #<Set: {3, 4}>
```